# register modules in object mapper globally

Tags: java, spring-boot, objectmapper, fasterxml

i have Topic class having a data member `duration` of type `LocalTime`

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name= "topics")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property  = "id",
    scope     = Long.class)
    @DynamicInsert(true)
    @DynamicUpdate(true)
    public class Topics implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1777454701749518940L;

        @Id
        @Column(name= "id")
        private Long id = Long.parseLong(UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8), 16);

        @NotEmpty
        @NotNull
        @Column(name= "topic", columnDefinition = "Text", length = 50000)
        private String topic;

        @Convert(converter = LocalTimeConverter.class)
        private LocalTime duration;

        // getters and setters
     }
```

input json:

```
{
    "topic":"x111",
    "imageUrl":"http://x.com/x1/x11/x111",
    "duration":"00:00:05"
}
```

error:

```
Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalTime: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('00:00:05')
```

solution:

```
POM.XML
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.findAndRegisterModules();

or

mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
      .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
      .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

it is working fine but how can i register modules globally.

i tried by extend `WebConfigurationAdapter`

```
@Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
                    .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
                    .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

        //objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();

        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        converters.add(converter);
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
```

but it didn't worked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just put this piece of code in your Main Spring Boot Application class

```
  @Autowired
  void configureObjectMapper(final ObjectMapper mapper) {
   mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
  .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
  .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
  }
```

That should do the trick.
You can even create a function with `@Bean`.
 And Instead of Creating ObjectMapper using `new`. Autowire the ObjectMapper in the class you need.